# Calculated field based on method inside Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I automatically populate a field in my PurchaseOrder model:

```
class PurchasedOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()


    @property
    def batch_cost(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.unit_price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

If I define it as a property, I won't be able to use this property to filter and stuff. I want it to be a calculated field.

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
def calculate_batch_cost(self):
    return self.quantity * self.product.unit_price

batch_cost = models.FloatField(default=calculate_batch_cost)
```

I will appreciate your help <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this field need to be specified and change anytime the object is created or updated, then you can add it inside the save funtion:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.batch_cost = self.calculate_batch_cost()
    super(PurchasedOrder, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And of course, you need to add the field inside the model

```
batch_cost = models.FloatField()
```

Then you can still use you `calculate_batch_cost` function elsewhere in you code.

Comment: Thanks pal! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) it in a `QuerySet`, like:

```
from django.db.models import F

PurchasedOrder.objects.annotate(
    batch_cost=F('product__unit_price') * F('quantity')
).filter(
    batch_cost__gt=100  # An example of filtering
)
```

The `PurchasedOrder`s from this queryset will have an attribute `.batch_cost` that is the `unit_price` of the product, times the `quantity`.

We can then for example filter on that one. For example in the above query, we will get all `PurchasedOrder`s with a `batch_cost` that is greater than `100`.

Comment: This was going to be my next question. Thanks pal!